# Как объединить grpc stubs и proto messages в один файл?

Tags: golang, grpc, google-protobuf

Всех приветствую, для генерации файла pb использую

> protoc --go_out=. --go-grpc_out=. protocol/api/*.proto

Но он создает два файла один с grpc stubs, второй с proto messages, как генерировать их в один файл?
У меня есть пример старого файла, где все в одном файле, никак не могу понять, как сделать точно так же.

Comment: офтоп: а в grpc можно вызывать функции на клиенте?